# WordPress. Прямая ссылка на php-скрипт

Tags: php, wordpress, api, битрикс

Нужно реализовать рабочую ссылку на php скрипт, к которому обращается по этой ссылке сервис извне. Пытался создать страницу и вставить туда разными способами.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/THEME/bitrix-integration/handler.php';
require get_template_directory_uri() . '/bitrix-integration/handler.php';
```

Но все они выдают 500 ошибку. Пробовал сделать тоже самое, в обычном сайте с обычным index.php, без Wordpress - по прямой ссылке заходит и статус 200.

Comment: А вручную если открыть будет 500?

Comment: А читать логи не пробовали? Причин 500 ошибки может быть куча!

Comment: В этом вашем handler.php должно загружаться ядро WordPress. Оно само по себе ниоткуда не возьмётся. Для загрузки там надо подключить файл `wp-load.php` из корня WP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Это переменная, определяемая в Битрикс. В ВордПресс ее нет. Вам нужно ее определить – прописать внутренний путь от корня